# Remove duplicate entries from an XDocument

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, xpath

I have a couple of lines of code that look like this.

```
XDocument rssDocDistinct = new XDocument(new XElement("rss",  
   new XElement("channel", 
      from node in rssDoc.Element("rss").Element("channel").Descendants("item") 
         select node)));
```

Can anyone help me figure out how to get only the distinct "items" in rssDoc?  I don't want any duplicates.

Thanks for any help.

Edit:

```
<rss version="2.0">
   <channel>
      <title></title>
      <link></link>
      <description></description>
      <copyright></copyright>
      <ttl></ttl>
      <item>
         <title></title>
         <description></description>
         <link></link>
         <pubDate></pubDate>
      </item>
      <item>
         <title></title>
         <description> </description>
         <link></link>
         <pubDate></pubDate>
      </item>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

rssDocDistinct should look like this with no duplicate item elements (item that has the same title, link, description, pubDate would only appear once)

```
  <item>
     <title></title>
     <description></description>
     <link></link>
     <pubDate></pubDate>
  </item>
  <item>
     <title></title>
     <description> </description>
     <link></link>
     <pubDate></pubDate>
  </item>
```

Edit:
Thanks for the help guys I got it by figuring out how to make a IEqualityComparer as polishchuc suggested.

```
public class ItemComparer : IEqualityComparer<XElement>
    {
        #region IEqualityComparer<XElement> Members

        public bool Equals(XElement x, XElement y)
        {
            return (string)x.Element("title") == (string)y.Element("title")
                && (string)x.Element("description") == (string)y.Element("description")
                && (string)x.Element("link") == (string)y.Element("link")
                && (string)x.Element("pubDate") == (string)y.Element("pubDate");
        }

        public int GetHashCode(XElement obj)
        {
            return ((string)obj.Element("title")).GetHashCode()
                + ((string)obj.Element("description")).GetHashCode()
                + ((string)obj.Element("link")).GetHashCode()
                + ((string)obj.Element("pubDate")).GetHashCode();
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

Comment: this depends on your measure of what "distinct" means, need to see sample xml, assuming it means "at least one attribute value different from any other item"

Comment: I just want all the duplicates removed.

Comment: without you posting your xml, no-one can give you a specific answer - how would we even know what attributes your "items" have?

Comment: I added the structure of my xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [`Enumerable.Distinct`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb338049%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) extension method. Implement your own `IEqualityComparer<XElement>` or (preferable) inherit from [`EqualityComparer<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132123.aspx) class, with your own logic of distinct based on your needs. Use it, e.g.:

```
var comparer = new YourXElementComparer();
XDocument rssDocDistinct = new XDocument(new XElement("rss",  
   new XElement("channel", 
      from node in rssDoc.Element("rss").Element("channel").Descendants("item")
            .Distinct(comparer) 
         select node)));
```

Comment: I want the duplicates removed. Sorry but i am not understanding what YourXElementComparer() is.

Comment: @theDawckta, `YourXElementComparer`it is your own implementation of `IEqualityComparer<XElement>` or derived from `EqualityComparer<T>` class.

Comment: I added the structure of my xml above, is there anyway you could assist me further?

Comment: @theDawckta, What do you mean as "distinct items"? Those which have the same title or those which have same title and same description or ...

Comment: I want to grab all the distinct items from the xml you see there and have the new rssDocDistinct have only the unique items, so if any item is the same then omit it if it has already been grabbed.

Comment: @theDawckta, What do you mean by unique items in your case? Those which have the same title or those which have same title and same description or ... Explain.